# Conditions in SQL to provide correct output

Tags: sql, select, unique, denormalization

I'm facing a tough problem.

I need to have the following table provide unique data, when I mean unique it only needs to have one customerID record. Also the price needs to be the max value.

```
--------------------------------------
customerID, basketID, orderID, productID, price
--------------------------------------
1, 1001, 101, 24, 15
1, 1001, 102, 24, 15
1, 1001, 103, 28, 19
```

As you can see that the orderID increments by one even though they're the same basket, customer and product. This shows the quantity of products.

Want I need from this is one record with 1 as the customerID but showing the max price.

```
--------------------------------------
customerID, basketID, orderID, productID, price
--------------------------------------
1, 1001, 103, 28, 19
```

The query must start with select, and Order By can not be used, as the system we're using doesn't support this.

If anyone has the slightest clue on what I should do it would be great.

Thanks.

Comment: How can your system not support ORDER BY? You have **no** guarantee of any row order without it.

Answer (score 0):

try the following:

```
SELECT customerID, basketID, orderID, productID, price
FROM TABLENAME t
WHERE price = (select max(price) from TABLENAME t2 where t.customerID = t2.customerID)
```

Comment: but i think it will get records for multiple customers with max price

Comment: but I thinks he wants the max price per customer/basket and not overall.

Answer (score 0):

The following will work if you have more that one customerID/basketID:

```
select t1.* from tablename t1
inner join (select customerID, basketID, max(Price) as Price from tablename
group by customerID, basketID) t2 on t1.customerID = t2.customerID and t1.basketID = t2.basketID and t1.Price = t2.Price
```

Answer (score 0):

try this :

```
SELECT * FROM t 
 WHERE (customer_id, price) IN (SELECT customer_id, MAX(price)
                                  FROM t GROUP BY customer_id)
```